# How would you use predicate logic to check if a statement is true or false?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

> Let $P(x,y,z)$ be the predicate $x+y<z$. Over which set is the statement   $∀z∃x∃y\ P(x,y,z)$ true?
>
> $\Bbb Z^+=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ or $\Bbb Z$?

I had thought that it would be neither, but that is not an option. Can someone please explain to me which one is correct and why? I am quite new to discrete mathematics so would greatly appreciate a walkthrough. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over $\Bbb Z^+$, because the smallest number is 1, *for any* $x$ and $y$ we have $x+y>1$, so the predicate is always false if $z=1$. Therefore the statement is false (we have shown its negation to be true).

Over $\Bbb Z$, the statement is true because *for any* $z$ we can take (*there exists*) $x=z$ and $y=-1$ such that $x+y=z-1<z$.